# pyaudio not working with 16000 samping rate using USB Audio devices index and getting error "Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997" in ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: python-2.7, audio, usb, ubuntu-12.04, pyaudio

I am trying in ubuntu 12.04 to play the wav files using the **pyaudio** and selecting the output device index -  USB Advanced Audio Device: USB Audio (hw:1,0) .

If I will select Frame rate 48000.000000 wav file and selected the output device index - USB Audio it's working fine ,I am able to hear .BUT
But if i choose Frame rate 16000.000000 wav file and selected the output device index - USB Audio it's working fine ,I am NOT able to hear,It's showing the following error :

---

```
Expression 'SetApproximateSampleRate( pcm, hwParams, sr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1968
Expression 'PaAlsaStreamComponent_InitialConfigure( &self->playback, outParams, self->primeBuffers, hwParamsPlayback, &realSr )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2646
Expression 'PaAlsaStream_Configure( stream, inputParameters, outputParameters, sampleRate, framesPerBuffer, &inputLatency, &outputLatency, &hostBufferSizeMode )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2767
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speech.py", line 34, in <module>
    output=True)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyaudio.py", line 714, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/pyaudio.py", line 396, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid sample rate] -9997
```

---

same sampling rate 16 k if I will select "default " device index it's working fine .My Code is simple to get the audio device output index and I am passing the output device index id

---

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("Plays a wave file.\n\nUsage: %s filename.wav" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(-1)

"""wf = wave.open('C:/Users/arunku2x/Desktop/bar_opening.wav', 'rb')"""

wf = wave.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

count = p.get_device_count()
devices = []
for i in range(count):
        devices.append(p.get_device_info_by_index(i))

for i, dev in enumerate(devices):
        print "%d - %s" % (i, dev['name'])

print "Sample Width %f" % wf.getsampwidth()
print "Number of channels %d" % wf.getnchannels()
print "Frame rate %f" % wf.getframerate()


#x = p.is_format_supported(rate = wf.getframerate(),output_device = 4 ,output_channels = wf.getnchannels(),output_format= p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()))
#print "format .............x %d" % x

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()),
        channels=wf.getnchannels(),
        rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output_device_index =4,#here 4 means - USB Audio device
        output=True)
data = wf.readframes(1024)
while data != '':
    stream.write(data)
    data=wf.readframes(1024)
```

---

Using PyAudio to play the sound .
Let me know if you any idea to work the 16k sampling rate using PyAudio with USB audio device.